# Displaying parent page on child page list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script that is displaying child page list on parent page and a list o child pages without the current child page.

I would like to add the parent page on child pages, but I don't know how to achieve it. Could you please help me out?

This is my code:

```
if ('page-parent') {
echo '<h3>See also</h3>';
  // if we are on a parent page set the $parent variable to current post id
  // otherwise set $parent variable to current post parent
  $parent = $post->post_parent == 0 ? $post->ID : $post->post_parent;

  // if we use current post parent as $parent, exclude the current page
  $exclude = $parent == $post->post_parent ? $post->ID : false;

  // get all the children
  $args = array( 'parent' => $parent, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' );
  if ( $exclude ) $args['exclude'] = $exclude;
  $child_pages = get_pages($args);

  // show only if there are children
  if ( ! empty($child_pages) ) {
    global $post;
    foreach ( $child_pages as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <div class="child-thumb">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'child_of' argument instead of 'parent'. 'parent' in get_pages means to fetch or not to fetch parental pages. 
But your case needs to fetch children of given page.

So you must use

```
$args = array( 'child_of' => $parent, 
'sort_column' => 'menu_order' );
```

To display one single parent page above children, you can use get_post function:

```
if ($post->post_parent>0){
$parent_page=get_post($post->post_parent);
echo '<div>'.$parent_page->post_title.'</div>';
}
if ( ! empty($child_pages) ) {
///and so on...
```

For more information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I have changed that, but I doesn't display the parent on child pages.

Comment: you can use get_post for that. i have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you @Elvin Haci :)