# Wordpress PHP, wp_list_pages() but only showing directory of current parent hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make make it so that when, following my page hierarchy laid out below, it would dynamically display the current page hierarchy of the page i am on and work across all instances.

- Home

1. About

- Staff
- Board
- Employment

2. Services

- Thing1
- Thing2
- Thing3

3. Custom Post Type

- Post1
- Post2
- Post3

So if I was on the Employment page it would show -

1. About

- Staff
- Board
- Employment

And if I were on the Thing1 page it would show -

2. Services

- Thing1
- Thing2
- Thing3

And also if I was on a single page in my custom post type, say Post2, it would show -

3. Custom Post Type

- Post1
- Post2
- Post3

I went down both of these rabbit holes and couldn't make it work.
[How to get all child pages of a parent page in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488429/how-to-get-all-child-pages-of-a-parent-page-in-wordpress)
[Displaying parent page on child page list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150135/displaying-parent-page-on-child-page-list)

The closest I came was this but it displayed ALL pages -

```
     <?php
  $currentpage = $post->ID;
  $parentpage = $post->post_parent;
  $grandparent = get_post_ancestors($currentpage);
  $grandparentID = $grandparent[1]; ?>

  <nav id="navStandard" class="mura-nav-standard sidebar-nav well">
    <ul>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'depth' => 2,
            'include' => $grandparentID,
            'title_li' => "",
            // add page id's for pages you dont want to show in the sidebar in the about section
            'exclude' => '32891,32893'
        );
        wp_list_pages($args);
        $args['child_of'] = $args['include'];
        unset($args['include']);
        wp_list_pages($args);
        ?>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Any help would be grateful. Thank you.

---

@Oleh Kosarenko
I have landed on something else that works across the board but still doesn't work when on customPostTypeName-single.php in the sidebar.
This is my URL hierarchy and you can see that I have changed the custom rewrite slug to "routes-and-maps/route-network"
"www___.test/routes-and-maps/route-network/adirondack-loop/"

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $currentpage = $post->ID;
  $grandparent = get_post_ancestors($post->ID); 
  $id = ($grandparent) ? $grandparent[count($grandparent)-1]: $post->ID;
  $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( array( $currentpage ) );
  ?>


  <?php if ($post->post_parent == 29992 || $post->post_parent == 33647 || $currentpage == 29992 || $currentpage== 33647 || $id == 29992 ||  $id == 33647) { ?>
    
    <nav id="navStandard" class="sidebar-nav well">
      <?php 
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => 'Routes Sidebar Menu',
        'theme_location' => '__no_such_location',
        'fallback_cb'    => false,
      ));
      ?>
    </nav>

  <?php } elseif`
```

When i   i get an error of "Warning: Array to string conversion in..." and when i   
i get the current post id. im still unable to get the main root page id of the "/routes-and-maps/" page id of 29992

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Perhaps you need to use the parameter 'child_of' and set the parent URL to 'title_li'.

```
<?php
global $post;
if(!empty($post->post_parent)):
?>
    <nav id="navStandard" class="mura-nav-standard sidebar-nav well">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'depth'    => 1,
                'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
                'title_li' => '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a>',
                // add page id's for pages you dont want to show in the sidebar in the about section
                'exclude'  => '32891,32893'
            );
            wp_list_pages( $args );
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Solution 2**

Here is another approach: By utilizing all the IDs and the 'include' parameter, you can obtain the list you need. For example:

```
<?php
global $post;
if(!empty($post->post_parent)):
    ?>
    <nav id="navStandard" class="mura-nav-standard sidebar-nav well">
        <ul>
            <?php
            $ids = [];
            $ids[] = $post->post_parent;
            $pages = get_pages( array(
                'parent' => $post->post_parent,
            ) );
            if(!empty($pages)){
                foreach ($pages as $page) {
                    $ids[] = $page->ID;
                }
            }
            $args = array(
                'depth' => 2,
                'include' => $ids,
                'title_li' => "",
                // add page id's for pages you dont want to show in the sidebar in the about section
                'exclude' => '32891,32893'
            );
            wp_list_pages($args);
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

P.S. Please write to me here if the problem is not solved.

Comment: This still did not work. It is just displaying all the posts and pages across the site

Comment: It seems I've found the solution. Look above for it in my main answer (with the code). If you have any questions, feel free to ask here again.

Comment: It seems that is essentially what I originally posted but put more eloquently. It is still showing all posts and pages, just with a depth of 1 instead of 2. If I change it to a depth of 2 it spits out exactly the same content that I had from my originally posted code. I'm wondering if it has something to do with me testing this in a custom post type's single page?

Oleh, thanks for the speedy response I really do appreciate it. I am unfortunately about to log out for the weekend. I hope you have a good one. Thanks

Comment: In fact, there are several differences here:

1. In your example, the $grandparentID variable is empty, resulting in the entire list of posts being fetched.
2. The 'title_li' parameter is used to define a link to the parent post.

Comment: Therefore, you should replace your code entirely with mine. After doing so, everything should work. Have a great weekend!)

Comment: Oleh, I am on a single.php of a custom post type, so when i print_r the $args for your first solution it gives me this - ````Array ( [depth] => 1 [child_of] => 0 [title_li] => Pacific Coast [exclude] => 32891,32893 )```` The child_of comes back with an ID of 0 which I think is the main issue here. Any clues?

Comment: Yes, child_of should not be set to zero. It's possible that you've used WP_Query before, and if that's the case, you should reset the post data using: [wp_reset_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/);